# Qt5: QPushButon size setting

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

it's a bit frustrating, but I can't find proper way to set QPushButton size. From what I read I suppose that this code should work:

```
// SEND BUTTON
sendButton = new QPushButton(this);
sendButton->setText("Send");
sendButton->setMinimumSize(QSize(0,0));
sendButton->setMaximumSize(QSize(10000,10000));
sendButton->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(30, 100),QSize(10, 20)));
connect(sendButton, &QPushButton::released, this, &MainWindow::handleSendButton);


// CENTRAL WIDGET
QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
centralWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);

// LAYOUT
QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout(centralWidget);
layout->addWidget(sendButton,0,0,0,0);
```

But the button is always expanded to the whole application window. Could you please help?

Comment: You do set its maximum size pretty large (reduce this). It will be maximized in the grid layout since it has no Spacers as neighbors. Try to build this in the designer, there you can see what happens and what code is generated.

Comment: Thanks, now I have better understanding of layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The policies that the Widgets have by default is `QSizePolicy::Preferred`, but in your case you should use `QSizePolicy::Fixed`.

> **QSizePolicy::Preferred**: The sizeHint() is best, but the widget can be
>   shrunk and still be useful. The widget can be expanded, but there is
>   no advantage to it being larger than sizeHint() (the default QWidget
>   policy).
>
> **QSizePolicy::Fixed**: The QWidget::sizeHint() is the only acceptable
>   alternative, so the widget can never grow or shrink (e.g. the vertical
>   direction of a push button).

In addition you must establish the alignment to be centered, so that from the above you get the following:

```
sendButton->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
layout->addWidget(sendButton,0,0,0,0, Qt::AlignCenter);
```